# How to implement the function find with the filter function?

Tags: haskell, filter, find

I'm making some exercise to practice my Haskell skills. My task is to implement the Haskell function `find` by myself with the `filter` function.

I already implemented the `find` function without the `filter` function (see codeblock below) but now my problem is to implement it with `filter` function.

```
-- This is the `find` function without `filter` and it's working for me.

find1 e (x:xs)= if e x then x
        else find1 e xs

-- This is the find function with the filter function 

find2 e xs = filter e xs
```

The result of `find1` is right

> ```
> *Main> find1(>4)[1..10]
> Output : [5].
> ```

But my actual task to write the function with filter gives me the

> ```
> *Main> find2(>4)[1..10]
> Output : [5,6,7,8,9,10].
> ```

My wanted result for `find2` is the result of `find1`.

Comment: `find1` needs a base case for the empty list? And if you just want the first result, use `head` but know it is unsafe (gives an error if no matching element in the list is found)

Comment: It seems that OP is looking for a reimplementation of `filter` (instead of `find`). He seems to call `filter` by the name of `find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "cut a list" to only have one, head element in it, use `take 1`:

```
> take 1 [1..]
[1]

> take 1 []
[]

> take 1 $ find2 (> 4) [1..10]
[5]

> take 1 $ find2 (> 14) [1..10]
[]
```

If you need to implement your own `take 1` function, just write down its equations according to every possible input case:

```
take1 [] = []
take1 (x:xs) = [x]
```

Or with `filter`,

```
findWithFilter p xs = take1 $ filter p xs
```

Your `find1` definition doesn't correspond to the output you show. Rather, the following definition would:

```
find1 e (x:xs) = if e x then [x]     -- you had `x`
                   else find1 e xs
find1 _ []     = []                  -- the missing clause
```

It is customary to call your predicate `p`, not `e`, as a mnemonic device. It is highly advisable to add type signatures to all your top-level definitions.

If you have difficulty in writing it yourself you can start without the signature, then ask GHCi which type did it infer, than use that signature *if it indeed expresses your intent* -- otherwise it means you've coded something different:

```
> :t find1
find1 :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> [t]
```

This seems alright as a first attempt.

Except, you actually intended that there would never be more than 1 element in the output list: it's either `[]` or `[x]` for some `x`, never more than one.

The list `[]` type is too permissive here, so it is not a perfect fit.

Such a type does exist though. It is called `Maybe`: values of type `Maybe t` can be either `Nothing` or `Just x` for some `x :: t` (read: `x` has type `t`):

```
import Data.Maybe  (listToMaybe)

find22 p xs = listToMaybe $ filter p xs
```

We didn't even have to `take 1` here: the function `listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a` (read: has a type of function with input in `[a]` and output in `Maybe a`) already takes at most one element from its input list, as the result type doesn't allow for more than one element -- it simply has no more room in it. Thus it expresses our intent correctly: at most one element is produced, if any:

```
> find22 (> 4) [1..10]
Just 5

> find22 (> 14) [1..10]
Nothing
```

Do add full signature above its definition, when you're sure it is what you need:

```
find22 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
```

Next, implement `listToMaybe` yourself. To do this, just follow the types, and write equations enumerating the cases of possible input, producing an appropriate value of the output type in each case, just as we did with `take1` above.

Comment: Thanks for imporve my function but unfortunately it was not the awnsere I was looking for. I´m still looking for the function find implemented with filter. Best regards :)

Comment: I gave it twice, as `take 1 $ find2 ...`, or `find22`, no? :) Do you mean you need `take 1` or `listToMaybe` implementation hints?

Comment: I've added something, but I must say that answering multi-pronged questions isn't fun. It makes for a confused mess of an answer. In the future please always ask one question about one particular code snippet.